# Is there an R function to convert 'flowFrame' structure of 'flowCore' package to a 'data.frame'?

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

Objective: To view .fcs data as a dataframe using R language.

Flow Cytometry data comes in **.fcs** file format. The file is read in the **flowFrame** structure producers using the read function of `flowCore` package. I want to read it in R. How can I convert it to `data.frame` structure?

The data looks as below: -

[image]

Comment: Please include a minimal example of such object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `exprs` function of the __ package.
Although its [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Biobase/versions/2.32.0/topics/exprs) isn't clearly stating this use case, it worked for me.

```
df = fcs@exprs
```

where,

```
fcs  =read.FCS("File_lcoation", truncate_max_range = FALSE)
```

Requirements: -

1. flowCore (read.FCS)-Code:

   if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))

   install.packages("BiocManager")

   BiocManager::install("flowCore")
2. MetaCyto (exprs)-Code:
   if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
   install.packages("BiocManager")

   BiocManager::install("MetaCyto")